# How can I use Find and Replace with REGEX to find a parameter and replace it with the parameter

Tags: sql, regex

As I don't know If the question was quite understandable, perhaps the problem is quite easy.

I'll give it as an example to show what I want:

I have a .sql file like:

```
CREATE TABLE Instituição(
//stuff inside
GO

CREATE TABLE Tutor(
//stuff inside
GO

CREATE TABLE Funcao(
//stuff inside
GO
```

with pretty much a bunch of these code alike, the first thing I want is to look up for "CREATE TABLE (something)", and after that this (something) to be replace in another sentence, which goes to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'SQL_DB..(something)', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE (something);
GO
```

to be added before the CREATE TABLE, so the code would be pretty much resulted to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'SQL_DB..Instituição', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE Instituição;
GO
CREATE TABLE Instituição(
//stuff inside
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'SQL_DB..Tutor', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE Tutor;
GO
CREATE TABLE Tutor(
//stuff inside
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'SQL_DB..Funcao', N'U') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE Funcao;
GO
CREATE TABLE Funcao(
//stuff inside
GO
```

As I was looking up, the regex code would be like this:
find:

```
CREATE TABLE {:q}
```

replace:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'SQL_DB..\1', N'U') IS NOT NULL\nDROP TABLE \1;\nGO\nCREATE TABLE \1
```

But it isn't working, how may I do it properly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What software are you doing this search and replace in?

Comment: Microsft SQL Server 2012, but I can use notepad++ if it needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In notepad++ you can use this:

Find what:

```
CREATE TABLE (.*?)\(
```

Replace with:

```
IF OBJECT_ID\(N'SQL_DB..\1', N'U'\) IS NOT NULL\nDROP TABLE \1;\nGO\nCREATE TABLE \1\(
```

Move the cursor to the beginning of the file and hit <kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

This will turn your sample input into your sample output.

What did I do? I escaped the parenthesis in the *Replace With* expression. Also included the `(` in the *find what* (so it is more accurate) and at the end of the *Replace With*.

Comment: Nice! I only knew about the \1 as the first captured sentence, but may I ask you a little bit of explanation? Well: () these are for capture group, .* is used to reference everything in that part, and the 'slash (' is to reference a single '(' character, which indicates the end of the search, but why the question mark?

Comment: The question mark makes the `*` operator "non-greedy", meaning it will match as little as possible (usually it matches as much as possible). Check this example: http://regexr.com?35f1u - add a `?` after the `*` and compare. Let me know if it is clear!

Comment: Excelent explanation, thank you very much \\Eu ri do brasil 3x0 espanha kkk, obrigado ai :)

Comment: Glad I could help! \\hahahuauhuha :D